# Using affine in Autocad Map 3D 2010

Tags: export, autocad

We have several DWG files that we would like to use as Layers in GeoServer.

Therefore, what is needed is to specify the coordinate of a certain point, rotate and scale the drawing prior to exporting it as SHP.

By clicking on Tools and Geographic Location, a certain point on the drawing can be geo-referenced.

Now, how can the other two tasks be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to move, scale, rotate, stretch your drawing with standard AutoCAD tools. Do not go into the coordinate systems with AutoCAD and shp files. AutoCAD Map has ability to set coordinate system to specific dwg file, but in some case it cannot be used because AutoCAD handles coordinate systems differently than most GIS applications, Geoserver being one of them. Place your drawing the best you can with standard AutoCAD drawing tools, export it do shp file and assign appropriate coordinates system in Geoserver.

Comment: Thank you very much Mario, but I still don't understand how a standard 100 meters x 100 meters block will be of that size, or will be rotated to point to North correctly? Do you suggest doing that scale and rotation in QGIS for example?

Comment: Personally, if I have vector data in dwg, I georeference it in AutoCAD. It is much much easier than in any GIS program.

Comment: I think I don't understand your problem exactly. If you have dwg drawing in some unknown coordinate system (and unknown units), to georeference it you have to have some identical points in your drawing and in some coordinate system. With standard AutoCAD tools you have to match those identical points. If that coordinate system is metric, then 100 units in AutoCAD is 100 meters. It is easy as that.

Comment: Thanks. My original question is about _how to do scale and rotation better in autocad_, as I'm an engineer and don't have strong autocad skills (perhaps I do it in an inefficient way). However, based on your answer I understood the possibility of just assign the CRS and match one point, in order to affine in a GIS software like the mentioned above.